# PaintComponent not drawing anything

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

```
public checkersView()
{
    super("Checkers");
    Content content=new Content();
    setContentPane(content);
    this.pack();
    this.repaint();
    checkersBoard boardOfChecks=new checkersBoard();
    add(boardOfChecks);
    Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation( (screensize.width - this.getWidth())/2,
            (screensize.height - this.getHeight())/2 );
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
}`public class Content extends JPanel{
    Content() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400,300) );
        resignButton = new JButton("Resign");
        newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
        message = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);
        message.setFont(new  Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        message.setForeground(Color.green);
        newGameButton.setBounds(210, 60, 120, 30);
        resignButton.setBounds(210, 120, 120, 30);
        message.setBounds(0, 200, 350, 30);
        add(newGameButton);
        add(resignButton);
        add(message);
    }
}`public class checkersBoard extends JPanel{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {...}`
```

After running in my main function, this is the result:

The function PaintComponent which is supposed to draw a checkersboard is never used...

[ss](http://prntscr.com/i40aoe)

edit: As it may not seem clear, all of those classes are inner classes of CheckersView

Comment: I would recommend posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and discussing your specific problem and attempts made before the MCVE.

Comment: Have you made sure the panel is visible after the image is loaded? A setVisible(false); setVisible(true); should update the panel.

Comment: @Ironcache great suggestion, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto expands to [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

First of all, class names should start with an upper case character. Follow Java convention and be consistent.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Layout manager will determine the size and location of components added to a panel.

By default Swing components have a size of (0, 0). Because you are using a null and you don't set the size properly there is nothing to paint.

So, use layout managers and you won't have this problem.

Also, read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). The examples will show how to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel to that your component will work properly with layout managers.

Comment: Adding setBounds to the boardOfCheckers seems to solve the case

Comment: `Adding setBounds` - that was NOT the suggestion I made. Learn to use Swing properliy and use layout managers (for too many reasons to list).